# Can I use Posts, Comments etc. from a Video in my App

Tags: youtube-api

I am currently developing an app where I want to combine some social networks. Youtube is one of those. I have some questions regarding the policies.

1. Is it allowed to show, posts, comments, pictures (comment photos, profile picture, post pictures, etc.), videos, like count, share count and everything the graph api provides me, commercially. Of course, only with the permission of the site owner. If not, what is allowed?
2. Am I allowed that the user can Like and Share posts/comments?
3. Can I place own adverts in my app? (not as video. The advert from youtube will be shown anyway)

I want you to answer my questions in a honest way.

Answer (score 0):

You can find YouTube's and YouTube's API terms of service linked below:

- [YouTube's Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms)
- [YouTube's API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms)